# tex4ht incompatible with expdlist

Tags: tex4ht

I try to convert the below document with `htlatex` and no options and it spits this error on me:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

There's no error if I remove the square brackets and their contents behind the description environment. There's another error, if I only include one item:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c:\end:itm 
l.7   \end{description}
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expdlist}
\begin{document}                                               
  \begin{description}[\breaklabel\setleftmargin{1ex}]
    \item[test1]text1
    \item[test2]text2
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it): this is better than `<pre>` in most cases as it does syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug.

Here is an ugly workaround:

```
\usepackage{expdlist}
\begin{document}     
  \ifx\HCode\UnDef
  \begin{description}[\breaklabel\setleftmargin{1ex}]
  \else
  \begin{description}
  \fi
    \item[test1]text1
    \item[test2]text2
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Update: https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?155

Update 2.  The bug is closed.  Until the patch travels to your system, just add the file `expdlist.4ht` to your work directory with the following contents:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% expdlist.4ht                          2011-11-20-04:55 %
% Copyright (C) 2007--2009       Eitan M. Gurari         %
%               2009--2011       TeX Users Group         %
%                                                        %
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the %
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either %
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any   %
% later version. The latest version of this license is   %
% in                                                     %
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt                %
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions %
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.                  %
%                                                        %
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".%
%                                                        %
% This Current Maintainer of this work                   %
% is the TeX4ht Project <tex4ht@tug.org>.                %
%                                                        %
% If you modify this program your changing its signature %
% with a directive of the following form will be         %
% appreciated.                                           %
%            \message{signature}                         %
%                                                        %
%                                        tex4ht@tug.org  %
%                             http://www.tug.org/tex4ht  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\immediate\write-1{version 2011-11-20-04:55}
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
%
%
% We just ignore optional arguments to description during ht run... 
%
\let\description@orig=\description
\def\description{\@ifnextchar[% ]
{\description@ht}{\description@orig}}
\def\description@ht[#1]{\description@orig}
\Hinput{expdlist}
\endinput
```

Comment: Ok, let's say it's a bug, is it tex4ht or expdlist?

Comment: I guess tex4ht.  I recently joined the team of tex4ht, so I promise to look at the bug asap :)

Comment: @cjorssen  I've closed the bug - see the update

Comment: Thank you very much for this fast answer! I've put the file in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/ and ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure tex4ht-common to make it found. (on Debian) Putting the file in the same dir as the latex file had no effect, maybe because I'm running htlatex from another dir to separate the output.

Comment: @Boris Thanks! There's still something I don't understand. What's the rule for the need of modifications to original macros in `<package>.4ht`. For example, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}` will work although `enumitem.4ht` does not redefine `\enumerate` to check for optional argument.

Comment: A great question.  The answer is, enumitem is dealt with in the core, for example, `html4.4ht`.  You see, for `enumitem` it is not enough to ignore the optional argument: we actually need to provide an HTML equivalent to the special formatting.  Perhaps I should do the same with `expdlist`, and try to map the special formatting of description into HTML; but for the time being I took the easy/lazy road.

Answer (score 1):

This works without any problems. The formating can be controlled with \Css{...} declarations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expdlist,lipsum}

\begin{document}                                               


\def\enditem{}
\def\enditemone{\Tg</dd>}

\ConfigureList{description}
    {\Tg<dl>}
    {\enditem\Tg</dl>}
    {\enditem\Tg<dt>}
    {\Tg</dt>\Tg<dd>\let\enditem\enditemone}

  \begin{description}[\breaklabel\setleftmargin{1ex}]
    \item[test1]\lipsum[1]
    \item[test2]\lipsum[2]
  \end{description}

\end{document}
```